# Problem with ToasterBox, can you join() a timer or force a thread to wait on a timer to finish in python

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, blocking

Basically I am using toasterbox and I want code to run, lets say every 30 seconds. Well every 30 seconds the toasterbox should pop up. The code looks like this

```
event = threading.Event()
#############################################
bWidth = 200
bHeight = 100
tb = TB.ToasterBox(self, TB.TB_COMPLEX, TB.DEFAULT_TB_STYLE, TB.TB_ONTIME)

tb.SetPopupSize((bWidth,bHeight))
tb.SetPopupPosition((1600-bWidth,900-bHeight))

tb.SetPopupPauseTime(4000)
tb.SetPopupScrollSpeed(8)
##############################################
while true:

    showPopup(tb,name,amount,progress,link)           
    tb.Play()

    event.wait(30)
```

That should give you an idea. Anyway the problem that occurs is, the toasterbox pops up but tb.play() isn't blocking because it spawns a timer to handle animation so the thread immediately continues to the wait function and blocks, so the toasterbox never closes. Is there a way to change the code for play to make it blocking? Or is there a better way to do this. I tried creating a new thread to run tb.play() in but it threw an error about only being able to run from the main thread. More info about toaster box including the source found here: [Toasterbox](http://toasterbox.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this toasterbox you're using? There's one included with wxPython. See here http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/toasterbox_module.html#toasterbox  or here http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.toasterbox.ToasterBox-class.html

I don't think the agw one supports blocking and I'm guessing the one you're using doesn't either. You can ask on the wxPython mailing list to see if they can patch their version or have a better suggestion. Personally, I would use a wx.Timer to pop up the toaster. That should take care of your problem without threads. There's an example of how to use timers here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/